# If a downed power line hits your car, why should you shuffle away from it?

Tags: electricity

A bit of fun! My colleague showed me a video at work about what to do if a downed power line lands on your car.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psv3ySUoF3Q&feature=youtu.be&t=54

In the video, the narrator says this about how to get out of the car:

> Remove all loose items or clothing and jump clear of the vehicle. Avoid 
>   touching the car and the ground at the same time. **Land with both feet together, keep your feet as close together as possible, and shuffle away from the car.**

My question is, what is the point of landing on both feet, keeping them close together, and shuffling away? How would this be more safe than simply sprinting away from the vehicle?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is to keep the difference of potential to a minimum. On the ground’s surface there may  varying voltage.

Answer (score 4):

A downed power line can create a voltage gradient across the ground. If your two feet touch areas that have a voltage difference, a current can flow up one leg and down the other, electrocuting you. By keeping your feet close together, you are minimizing the potential for this to happen, as nearby points on the ground will in general exhibit a lower voltage difference than distant points.

The better option is to just stay in the car, though, so long as there's no imminent danger from fire or explosion. Evacuating a car with a live wire on it is dangerous; it's better to stay in the car until the line has been de-energized, if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully I never have to put this advice into practice.

Comment: Does sitting in a sheet metal cage atop a tank of gasoline with arcing high voltage power lines somehow not count as imminent danger for you?

Comment: @DuncanHarris If the car is not on fire, the danger is less imminent than what you'd face by evacuating.

Comment: @DuncanHarris How likely is that to happen in a gas tank?  It almost seems like it would act as a pretty good Faraday cage, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think the safety of the car depends a lot on little things like whether oil is coating the outside of various parts under the hood that could see a spark.  I drive old cars and would rather trust myself not to screw up hopping out of the car than trust my car not to explode.  That’s just me.  Maybe the risks feel different for someone else.